# GODOT Error type 3 Error: Activity class does not exist

Tags: android, godot

I am trying to run GODOT game on my le eco 1s using USB debug option and i i am facing this problem.

This what console shows at the end of this we see the error message

```
  s = signature was verified
  m = entry is listed in manifest
  k = at least one certificate was found in keystore
  i = at least one certificate was found in identity scope

- Signed by "CN=Ashwin Nandihalli, OU=Game Development, O=colourbees.com, L=bang
alore, ST=Karnataka, C=IN"
    Digest algorithm: SHA1
    Signature algorithm: MD5withRSA, 2048-bit key

jar verified.

Warning:
This jar contains entries whose certificate chain is not validated.
This jar contains signatures that does not include a timestamp. Without a timest
amp, users may not be able to validate this jar after the signer certificate's expiration date (2044-08-01) or after any future revocation date.

Re-run with the -verbose and -certs options for more details.
Uninstalling previous version: Letv Le X507
running cmdline: "C:/Users/prayag/AppData/Local/Android/sdk1/platform-tools/adb.exe" "-s" "IVYLFUSGCM9HAYLN" "uninstall" "org.colourbees.$madmath"
Failure [DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR]
Installing into device (please wait..): Letv Le X507
running cmdline: "C:/Users/prayag/AppData/Local/Android/sdk1/platformtools/adb.
exe" "-s" "IVYLFUSGCM9HAYLN" "install" "-r" "C:\Users\prayag\AppData\Roaming/God
ot/tmp/tmpexport.apk"
[100%] /data/local/tmp/tmpexport.apk
Please select on your phone whether can install the app by The ADB command?
        pkg: /data/local/tmp/tmpexport.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK]
running cmdline: "C:/Users/prayag/AppData/Local/Android/sdk1/platform-tools/adb.exe" "reverse" "--remove-all"
running cmdline: "C:/Users/prayag/AppData/Local/Android/sdk1/platformtools/adb.exe" "reverse" "tcp:6007" "tcp:6007"
Reverse result: 0
running cmdline: "C:/Users/prayag/AppData/Local/Android/sdk1/platformtools/adb.exe" "reverse" "tcp:6010" "tcp:6010"
Reverse result2: 0
running cmdline: "C:/Users/prayag/AppData/Local/Android/sdk1/platformtools/adb.exe" "-s" "IVYLFUSGCM9HAYLN" "shell" "am" "start" "-a" "android.intent.action.MA
IN" "-n" "org.colourbees.$madmath/org.godotengine.godot.Godot"
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cmp=org.colourbees./org.godote
ngine.godot.Godot }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {org.colourbees./org.godotengine.godot.Godot} does not exist.
```

Answer (score 0):

I had changed this "Unique Name" `"org.companyname.$gamename"`

and reset this back to what shown in the image bellow which is default value
[image]
It just worked fine. USB debug is working and game is running on the phone